# An integer valued function that generate repeating integer for n amount of times in algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently I've made this function $f(x)=\frac{x+\frac{(-1)^x-1}{2}}{2}$ or $f(x)=\frac{2x+(-1)^x-1}{4}$ where $x$ is an integer. And it generate integers repeated two times, such as: $...,-3,-3,-2,-2,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,...$

So the question is: Is there any function where it could repeat itself for $n$ number of times? Like 3 times, $...,-3,-3,-3,-2,-2,-2,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,....$

Although knowing the function is $f(x)=\frac{2x+(-1)^x-1}{4}$ , I could derive a function that repeats the integer for $2^n$ times by putting the output of the function $f(x)$ into the function $f(x)$ again, or like $f(f(x))$ and $f(f(f(x)))$ and so on.

Edit: I forget to add that I only know middle school math, if there are any formula that only use algebraic expression that would be helpful.

Comment: Note that the floor function is a standard and easy-to-understand function. See the link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function should do the job:$$f(x) = \left\lfloor \frac x3 \right\rfloor $$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

(Also, see [floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) for more information)

---

Note that, your function could also be written in fancy way as
$$f(x)=\frac{2x+(-1)^x-1}{4} = \left\lfloor \frac x2 \right\rfloor$$
since when $x$ is even the numerator is divisible by $4$, and when $x$ is odd the numerator gives remainder of $2$ when divided by $4$ so you subtract $2$ to make it divisible by $4$

---

Therefore, this function can easily be generalized by just adjusting the denominator of the floor function.

Answer (score 2):

One relatively simple function using integer $x$ inputs to get each integer repeating itself $n$ times in the output is using the floor function to get

$$f(x) = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Alternatively, another function you can use is the ceiling function, with the output values shifted to the left $n - 1$ positions compared to the results of \eqref{eq1A}, to instead get

$$f(x) = \left\lceil \frac{x}{n} \right\rceil \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

A somewhat convoluted method is to use a piece-wise function, e.g., to get the same output as \eqref{eq1A}, use

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
m, & \text{if } x = mn, \; m \in \mathbb{Z} \\
m, & \text{if } x = mn + 1, \; m \in \mathbb{Z} \\
m, & \text{if } x = mn + 2, \; m \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\; \vdots & \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \vdots \\
m, & \text{if } x = mn + n - 1, \; m \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}
\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: What is that symbol? Would you mind telling me, I only know algebra precalculus or middle school stuff..

Comment: @Sometimesomewhere The $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$ symbols denote "floor" function which is the largest integer less than or equal to the argument. Thus, for example, $\left\lfloor \frac{1}{3} \right\rfloor = 0$, $\left\lfloor \frac{-2}{3} \right\rfloor = -1$, $\left\lfloor \frac{3}{3} \right\rfloor = 1$, $\left\lfloor \frac{4}{3} \right\rfloor = 1$, etc. For more details, please read the Wikipedia article [Floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).